# Empty List when i fetch data from database Web Api .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design, entity-framework-5, code-first

I'm using Entity Framework with repositories, Code First, Code First Migrations and Web Api. I have Town and City classes, they look this way:

```
public class Town
{
    public int TownId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public List<Town> Towns { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public City()
    {
        Towns = new List<Town>();
    }
}
```

this is my DbContext:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Town> Towns { get; set; }
  }
```

This is my Seed method [Configuration.cs (Migration folder)]

```
context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(s => s.Name,
            new City
            {
                Name = "Pinar del Río",
                Towns = new List<Town>()
                {
                    new Town() {Name = "Consolación del Sur"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Guane"},
                    new Town() {Name = "La Palma"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Los Palacios"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Mantua"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Minas de Matahambre"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Pinar del Río"},
                    new Town() {Name = "San Juan y Martínez"},
                    new Town() {Name = "San Luis"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Sandino"},
                    new Town() {Name = "Viñales"}

                }
            }
)
```

this is town table data(Database)
[image: Town Table in database]

[image: city data in database] table cities data(Database)

this is my repostory

```
public  class EFLocalizationRepository:ILocalizationRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<City> Cities { get { return context.Cities; } }

    public List<Town> GetTowns(int cityId)
    {
        var c = context.Cities.Find(cityId); //here ok
        var tws = context.Cities.Find(cityId).Towns; // but here is empty
        return tws;
    }
}
```

when i fetch towns i got an empty list, why?

Comment: Have you tried var tws = c.Towns; I can't think about why you get an emty list, but since you have get the city you want above, why you are not try to get it's towns?

Comment: yes, i did it. But it's the same

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the variable c, and then start debug, F10, and right click on c and then QuickWatch. Do you see there the towns list?

Comment: yes i did it, but it's empty

Comment: thats seems then pretty weird ! since you get right city but not it's town? When you say here ok you mean that for cityId=1 you get the city we show on your table. Right?

Comment: exactly, and if i do this query: Select * from dbo.Towns where CityId = 3, in database, it shows the correct result... :(

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
    var tws = context.Cities.Find(cityId).Towns.toList();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: well then you can check if lazy loading is enabled.

Comment: i did Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; in my Context class, and nothing!